# R - Sample while still keeping the same proportion of some categorical variable

Tags: r, sample

I'd like to make a random training sample and test sample from my dataset (something like 80%-20%). However, I have a categorical variable, which is either 0 or 1, and would like to keep the proportion of 1s vs 0s the same in both samples. I tried a couple different things, such as `sample_frac`, but to no success.

How can one do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technical term for this is 'stratified sampling', and the folks at RStudio made `rsample` for this very purpose. Use the `initial_split()` function and set `strata =` to the categorical variable you want to have an even proportion across sets. Use `training()` on the initial split to access your training set and likewise with `testing()`:

```
library(rsample)

set.seed(2021)
split <- rsample::initial_split(iris, prop = 0.8, strata = Species)

training_set <- rsample::training(split)
testing_set <- rsample::testing(split)
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a shorter way but this works for you. I used mtcars as an example. In the first version, I just sampled from the whole thing and we see different sizes in the 'am' factor (which is binary, 0/1), In the second instance I split the data frame in two and used sample_n to take x number of rows from each, then recombined.

```
mtcars <- mtcars

sampled <- sample(nrow(mtcars), nrow(mtcars) * 0.5)
sampled

mtcars_sampled <- mtcars[sampled,]
mtcars_sampled
  
nrow(mtcars_sampled)

mtcars_sampled %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  summarize(count = length(am))
```

[image]

```
mtcars_group_one <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(am == 1)

mtcars_group_two <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(am == 0)

sampled_one <- sample_n(mtcars_group_one, size = 8)
sampled_one

sampled_two <- sample_n(mtcars_group_two, size = 8)
sampled_two

sampled_even_weight <- bind_rows(sampled_one, sampled_two)
nrow(sampled_even_weight)

sampled_even_weight %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  summarize(count = length(am))
```

[image]

At the end, for splitting the data into test/train, I would do this:

```
  train.rows <- sample(nrow(sampled_even_weight), nrow(sampled_even_weight) * 0.8)
  mtcars_train <- sampled_even_weight[train.rows,]
  mtcars_test <- sampled_even_weight[-train.rows,]
```